# Синтаксис PHP, с массивом

Tags: php7

такой вопрос.
Есть код

```
    $xml = '
<product>
    <category-id type="integer">'.$import_category_id.'</category-id>
    <is-hidden type="boolean">false</is-hidden>
    <title>'.$filter2.'</title>
    <description>'.$filter.'</description>
    <variants-attributes type="array">
        <variants-attribute>
            <sku>'.$sku.'</sku>
            <price type="decimal">'.$price.'</price>
            <quantity type="integer">'.$quantity.'</quantity>
        </variants-attribute>
    </variants-attributes> 

</product>
```

';

Необходимо в него вставить цикл с массивом:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($param_value); $i++) 
    { 
    echo $param_value[$i].' - '.$param_name[$i]."<br />"; 
    }
```

чтобы на выходе получилось вот так:

```
            $xml = '
        <product>
            <category-id type="integer">'.$import_category_id.'</category-id>
            <is-hidden type="boolean">false</is-hidden>
            <title>'.$filter2.'</title>
            <description>'.$filter.'</description>


<properties-attributes type="array">
    <properties-attribute>
        <title>1</title>
        <value>2</value>
    </properties-attribute>
    <properties-attribute>
        <title>1</title>
        <value>2</value>
    </properties-attribute>
    <properties-attribute>
        <title>1</title>
        <value>2</value>
    </properties-attribute>
    <properties-attribute>
        <title>1</title>
        <value>2</value>
    </properties-attribute>
</properties-attributes>


            <variants-attributes type="array">
                <variants-attribute>
                    <sku>'.$sku.'</sku>
                    <price type="decimal">'.$price.'</price>
                    <quantity type="integer">'.$quantity.'</quantity>
                </variants-attribute>
            </variants-attributes> 

        </product> ';
```

Все переменные передаются функцией так же как и массив.

Comment: Александр, что вы сделали для решения своей проблемы? С чем столкнулись? Уточните, пожалуйста, проблему в вопросе. За вас работу никто делать не будет, тут не фриланс

Comment: Нет не решил. Есть скрипт который парсит товар с XML и отправляет его с  помощью API в том же формате (XML). Моя проблема заключается в том что я не могу сделать правильный синтаксис что бы передать все параметры товара. Я новенький в PHP и только учусь